# PerformancePoint vs PowerPivot > Which one

Tags: performancepoint, powerpivot

I have not worked with either one. So before I get deep into either one I want to make sure I am picking the right engine for business intelligence.

There are needs for reports, pie charts or charts, etc. You get the point. Also, my manager is interested in Dashboard (not sure if this is only achieved thru PerformanceP or PPivot)?

Please suggest the best way to do this. We do not have hardware constrains.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Getting started with business intelligence in SharePoint Server 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=14834) has a good comparison.

Also there is document "choosing the right Microsoft BI Tool.doc" (search on internet) which can help you. Below is captured from the document.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I did a webinar on this topic : http://bit.ly/AvFhgj "Choosing an MS Visualisation technology"

Angie: You can use combine PPS scorecards with RS reports on a Sharepoint page to get this interactivity. I also did a webinar on this :)

http://bit.ly/FPmRkK

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL Server Reporting Services if you need reporting (and it has extensive charting functionality, too).

Comment: Can it do where you click on a the pie or chart and correspondent data would show up.